# UIAlertController example - Swift - IOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I would create something like this with an UIAlertController:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Show us what you've tried and it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score -1):

My Suggestion is you can use library, which shows modal presentation of view controller, or you can directly show it as modal presentation.

if this is my case then i should use https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetPresentationController

It's really a cool library